# How can I display Firebase items in Android ListView?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to display some Firebase records in an Android ListView.  At present, my code is returning a solitary `0` to the `ListView` when I go to enter a new record, however my Firebase database is displaying the information that I want perfectly.

I have spent quite a bit of time over this issue and can't quite seem to pinpoint the problem.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Below is my code for displaying/adding new records:

```
    TenantList tenantListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_tenants);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String uid = user.getUid();

        //databaseTenantsList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tenants").child(uid);

        textViewPropertyName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPropertyName);
        editTextTenantsName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTenantsName);
        seekBarAge = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarAge);

        buttonAddTenant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddTenant);

        listViewTenants = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTenants);
        tenants = new ArrayList<>();
        tenantListAdapter = new TenantList(this, tenants);
        listViewTenants.setAdapter(tenantListAdapter);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        tenants = new ArrayList<>();

        String id = intent.getStringExtra(PropertyActivity.PROPERTY_ID);
        String name = intent.getStringExtra(PropertyActivity.PROPERTY_NAME);

        textViewPropertyName.setText(name);

        databaseTenants = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tenants").child(uid).child(id).child(uid);

        //databaseTenants = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tenants").child(id);

        buttonAddTenant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveTenant();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseTenants.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tenants.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot tenantSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Tenant tenant = tenantSnapshot.getValue(Tenant.class);

                    tenants.add(tenant);
                }
                tenantListAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void saveTenant() {

        String tenantName = editTextTenantsName.getText().toString().trim();
        int age = seekBarAge.getProgress();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(tenantName)){

            String id = databaseTenants.push().getKey();

            Tenant tenant = new Tenant(id, tenantName, age);

            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            String uid = user.getUid();

            databaseTenants.child(uid).child(id).setValue(tenant);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Tenant saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Tenant name should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**TenantList**

```
    public class TenantList extends ArrayAdapter<Tenant> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<Tenant> tenants;

    public TenantList(Activity context, List<Tenant> tenants) {

        super(context, R.layout.tenant_list_layout, tenants);
        this.context = context;
        this.tenants = tenants;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tenant_list_layout, null, true);

        TextView textViewTenant = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewTenant);
        TextView textViewAge = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewAge);

        Tenant tenant = tenants.get(position);
        textViewTenant.setText(tenant.getTenantName());
        textViewAge.setText(String.valueOf(tenant.getTenantAge()));

        return listViewItem;

    }
}
```

To add a bit more context, here is my data structure:

[image: Data Structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I'm seeing there's still one level until you get to the tennat object.

```
databaseTenants = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tenants").child(uid).child(id).child(uid);
```

Also, pull your adapter creation to the onCreate method so you can access it globally:

Add a  member variable:

```
TenantList tenantListAdapter
```

and initialize it after your listview, pull the tennants to before the adapter instantiation so you can access it:

```
listViewTenants = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTenants);
tenants = new ArrayList<>();
tenantListAdapter = new TenantList(this, tenants);
listViewTenants.setAdapter(tenantListAdapter);
```

Then, in your event listener just do:

```
databaseTenants.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tenants.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot tenantSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){ 
                    for(DataSnapshot lastSnapshot: tenantSnapshot.getChildren()){ 
                       Tenant tenant = lastSnapshot.getValue(Tenant.class); 
                       tenants.add(tenant); 
                    } 
                 } 
               tenantListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I am getting an error at `notifyDatasetChanged`. I have updated my question with your solution implemented. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I made a typo, it is notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Still getting the `0` as an output. This is present in my LogCat `04-01 16:11:51.753 9071-9071/com.example.xxx.myapplication E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length`. Not sure that is relevant

Comment: could you post your tenantListAdapter?

Comment: could you add a breakpoint here  tenantListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and check if  the list tenants have anything in it?

Comment: I added the breakpoint and the records are still being added to Firebase yes. I just don't understand why it is adding `0`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167997/discussion-between-levi-albuquerque-and-wright-arturo).